# messagebox appears twice when using event ListView_ItemSelectionChanged

Tags: vb.net

I used a listview (to simplify i added one item) and when i click it  a messagebox  is shown.
when i close the messagebox and click again the item  the messagebox appears twice i must to close it twice

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
        Select Case e.ItemIndex
            Case 0
                MessageBox.Show("AAAA")
        End Select

    End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [SelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event fires when an item is selected or deselected. If you only care about when an item is selected, try checking if the item is selected first.

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemSelectionChanged
    If Not e.IsSelected Then Exit Sub
    Select Case e.ItemIndex
        Case 0
            MessageBox.Show("AAAA")
    End Select
End Sub
```